# Combining CurrentHour and CurrentMinute from TimePicker

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite

I have an application which stores the CurrentHour and CurrentMinute from a TimePicker in a sqlite database then displays it in another activity  ViewCountry java

I would like to combine these two fields in and display them together 9:30 - for example in the

```
<TextView 
   android:id="@+id/codeText"
   style="@style/StyleText"/>
```

of view_country xml

add_country xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical" 
      android:padding="5dp">

      <EditText android:id="@+id/nameEdit"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:imeOptions="actionNext" 
         android:hint="@string/name_hint"
         android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords"/>

      <EditText android:id="@+id/capEdit"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:imeOptions="actionNext" 
         android:hint="@string/cap_hint"
         android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Data Limit"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="10MB" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="Unlimited Data" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Bandwidth Limit"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="10kbs" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Unlimited Bandwidth" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall" />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="WiFi Time Limit"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/timeEdit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" />

     <EditText
        android:id="@+id/codeEdit"
        android:inputType="textUri"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:lines="1"
        android:hint="@string/code_hint"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext" />

      <Button android:id="@+id/saveBtn" 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:text="@string/save_btn"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

**ADDEDITCOUNTRY**

quite possible minute values from TimePicker here are messing things up

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class AddEditCountry extends Activity {

 private long rowID; 
 private EditText nameEt;
 private EditText capEt;
 private EditText codeEt;
 private TimePicker timeEt;
 private TimePicker minEt;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
      setContentView(R.layout.add_country);

      nameEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameEdit);
      capEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.capEdit);
      codeEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.codeEdit);
      timeEt = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timeEdit);
      minEt = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timeEdit);

      Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 

      if (extras != null)
      {
         rowID = extras.getLong("row_id");
         nameEt.setText(extras.getString("name"));  
         capEt.setText(extras.getString("cap"));  
         codeEt.setText(extras.getString("code"));  
         timeEt.setCurrentHour(extras.getInt("time"));
         minEt.setCurrentMinute(extras.getInt("min"));
      }

      Button saveButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);
      saveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          public void onClick(View v) 
          {
             if (nameEt.getText().length() != 0)
             {
                AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> saveContactTask = 
                   new AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>() 
                   {
                      @Override
                      protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) 
                      {
                         saveContact();
                         return null;
                      }

                      @Override
                      protected void onPostExecute(Object result) 
                      {
                         finish();
                      }
                   }; 

                saveContactTask.execute((Object[]) null); 
             }

             else
             {
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddEditCountry.this);
                alert.setTitle(R.string.errorTitle); 
                alert.setMessage(R.string.errorMessage);
                alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.errorButton, null); 
                alert.show();
             }
          } 
     });
   }

       private void saveContact() 
       {
          DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(this);

          if (getIntent().getExtras() == null)
          {
              dbConnector.insertContact(nameEt.getText().toString(),
                      capEt.getText().toString(),
                      timeEt.getCurrentHour().toString(),
                      minEt.getCurrentMinute().toString(),
                      codeEt.getText().toString());
          }
          else
          {
             dbConnector.updateContact(rowID,
                nameEt.getText().toString(),
                capEt.getText().toString(),
                timeEt.getCurrentHour().toString(), /* Storing as String*/
                minEt.getCurrentMinute().toString(), 
                codeEt.getText().toString());
          }
       }
}
```

**DATABASECONNECTOR JAVA**

```
 import android.content.ContentValues;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.database.Cursor;
 import android.database.SQLException;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

   public class DatabaseConnector {

private static final String DB_NAME = "WorldCountries";
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private DatabaseOpenHelper dbOpenHelper;

public DatabaseConnector(Context context) {
    dbOpenHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
}

   public void open() throws SQLException 
   {
      //open database in reading/writing mode
      database = dbOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
   } 

   public void close() 
   {
      if (database != null)
         database.close();
   }       

   public void insertContact(String name, String cap, String code, String time, String min) 
           {
              ContentValues newCon = new ContentValues();
              newCon.put("name", name);
              newCon.put("cap", cap);
              newCon.put("time", time);
              newCon.put("min", min);
              newCon.put("code", code);

              open();
              database.insert("country", null, newCon);
              close();
           }

           public void updateContact(long id, String name, String cap,String code,  String time, String min) 
           {
              ContentValues editCon = new ContentValues();
              editCon.put("name", name);
              editCon.put("cap", cap);
              editCon.put("time", time);
              editCon.put("min", min);
              editCon.put("code", code);

              open();
              database.update("country", editCon, "_id=" + id, null);
              close();
           }

           public Cursor getAllContacts() 
           {
              return database.query("country", new String[] {"_id", "name"}, 
                 null, null, null, null, "name");
           }

           public Cursor getOneContact(long id) 
           {
              return database.query("country", null, "_id=" + id, null, null, null, null);
           }

           public void deleteContact(long id) 
           {
              open(); 
              database.delete("country", "_id=" + id, null);
              close();
           }
 }
```

**DATABASEOPENHELPER JAVA**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context context, String name,
        CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String createQuery = "CREATE TABLE country (_id integer primary key autoincrement,name, cap, code,  time, min);";                 
    db.execSQL(createQuery);        
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
 }
```

How can I combine the currentMinute and currentHour into one text field so it displays in a normal time format [ex 9:30]

## UPDATE AFTER fcm's SOLUTION/SUGGESTION:

## JAVA

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.content.Context;


public class AddEditCountry extends Activity {

     private long rowID; 
     private EditText nameEt;
     private EditText capEt;
     private EditText codeEt;
     private TimePicker timeEt;
     private TimePicker minEt;
     private String cHour;
     private String cMinute;
     private String normalTimeFormat;

       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
       {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
          setContentView(R.layout.add_country);

          nameEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameEdit);
          capEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.capEdit);
          codeEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.codeEdit);
          timeEt = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timeEdit);
          minEt = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timeEdit);



          Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 

          if (extras != null)
          {
             rowID = extras.getLong("row_id");
             nameEt.setText(extras.getString("name"));  
             capEt.setText(extras.getString("cap"));  
             codeEt.setText(extras.getString("code"));  
             timeEt.setCurrentHour(extras.getInt("time"));
             minEt.setCurrentMinute(extras.getInt("min"));
          }

          Button saveButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);
          saveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

              public void onClick(View v) 
              {
                 if (nameEt.getText().length() != 0)
                 {
                    AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> saveContactTask = 
                       new AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>() 
                       {
                          @Override
                          protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) 
                          {
                             saveContact();
                             return null;
                          }

                          @Override
                          protected void onPostExecute(Object result) 
                          {
                             finish();
                          }
                       }; 

                    saveContactTask.execute((Object[]) null); 
                 }

                 else
                 {
                    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddEditCountry.this);
                    alert.setTitle(R.string.errorTitle); 
                    alert.setMessage(R.string.errorMessage);
                    alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.errorButton, null); 
                    alert.show();
                 }
              } 
         });
       }


           private void saveContact() 
           {
              DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(this);

              if (getIntent().getExtras() == null)
              {
                  dbConnector.insertContact(nameEt.getText().toString(),
                          capEt.getText().toString(),
                          timeEt.getCurrentHour().toString(),
                          minEt.getCurrentMinute().toString(),
                          codeEt.getText().toString());
              }
              else
              {
                  dbConnector.updateContact(rowID,
                          nameEt.getText().toString(),
                          capEt.getText().toString(),


                          String cHour = timeEt.getCurrentHour().toString(), /* Storing as String*/
                          String cMinute = minEt.getCurrentMinute().toString(), 
                          String normalTimeFormat = cHour + ":" + cMinute;

                          //Do whatever you want to do with normalTimeFormat

                          codeEt.getText().toString());
                    }
           }
}
```

## UPDATED LOGCAT:

```
03-22 14:35:00.174: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(1320): <ConfigWindowMatch:2165>: Format RGBA_8888.
03-22 14:35:00.174: D/memalloc(1320): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5ca41000 size:614400 offset:0 fd:57
03-22 14:35:00.184: E/(1320): Can't open file for reading
03-22 14:35:00.184: E/(1320): Can't open file for reading
03-22 14:35:00.225: D/memalloc(1320): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5d12e000 size:614400 offset:0 fd:61
03-22 14:35:02.087: D/Activity(1320): Activity.onPause(), editTextTapSensorList size: 0
03-22 14:35:02.127: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(1320): <ConfigWindowMatch:2165>: Format RGBA_8888.
03-22 14:35:02.127: D/memalloc(1320): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5d4ce000 size:614400 offset:0 fd:64
03-22 14:35:02.227: D/memalloc(1320): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5d6f7000 size:614400 offset:0 fd:71
03-22 14:35:02.247: D/memalloc(1320): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5ca41000 size:614400
03-22 14:35:02.247: D/memalloc(1320): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5d12e000 size:614400
03-22 14:35:02.917: D/memalloc(1320): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5c929000 size:614400 offset:0 fd:56
03-22 14:35:04.319: D/Activity(1320): Activity.onPause(), editTextTapSensorList size: 0
03-22 14:35:04.509: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(1320): <ConfigWindowMatch:2165>: Format RGBA_8888.
03-22 14:35:04.509: D/memalloc(1320): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5ca41000 size:614400 offset:0 fd:60
03-22 14:35:04.599: D/memalloc(1320): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5dc02000 size:614400 offset:0 fd:75
03-22 14:35:04.619: D/memalloc(1320): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5dca8000 size:614400 offset:0 fd:78
03-22 14:35:04.629: D/memalloc(1320): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5d4ce000 size:614400
03-22 14:35:04.629: D/memalloc(1320): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5d6f7000 size:614400
03-22 14:35:04.629: D/memalloc(1320): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5c929000 size:614400
03-22 14:35:08.433: W/dalvikvm(1320): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x410889d8)
03-22 14:35:08.453: E/AndroidRuntime(1320): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
03-22 14:35:08.453: E/AndroidRuntime(1320): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
03-22 14:35:08.453: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
03-22 14:35:08.453: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
03-22 14:35:08.453: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
03-22 14:35:08.453: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
03-22 14:35:08.453: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
03-22 14:35:08.453: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
03-22 14:35:08.453: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
03-22 14:35:08.453: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
03-22 14:35:08.453: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-22 14:35:08.453: E/AndroidRuntime(1320): Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
03-22 14:35:08.453: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):     String cannot be resolved to a variable
03-22 14:35:08.453: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):     Syntax error on token "cHour", delete this token
03-22 14:35:08.453: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):     String cannot be resolved to a variable
03-22 14:35:08.453: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):     Syntax error on token "cMinute", delete this token
03-22 14:35:08.453: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):     Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodInvocation
03-22 14:35:08.453: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):     Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements
03-22 14:35:08.453: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):     String cannot be resolved to a variable
03-22 14:35:08.453: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):     Syntax error on token ")", delete this token
03-22 14:35:08.453: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):     at com.nfc.linkingmanager.AddEditCountry.saveContact(AddEditCountry.java:122)
03-22 14:35:08.453: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):     at com.nfc.linkingmanager.AddEditCountry.access$1(AddEditCountry.java:103)
03-22 14:35:08.453: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):     at com.nfc.linkingmanager.AddEditCountry$1$1.doInBackground(AddEditCountry.java:76)
03-22 14:35:08.453: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
03-22 14:35:08.453: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
03-22 14:35:08.453: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):     ... 5 more
03-22 14:35:08.493: D/Activity(1320): Activity.onPause(), editTextTapSensorList size: 0
03-22 14:35:08.563: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(1320): <ConfigWindowMatch:2165>: Format RGBA_8888.
03-22 14:35:08.563: D/memalloc(1320): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5d4bb000 size:614400 offset:0 fd:56
03-22 14:35:08.573: D/memalloc(1320): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5d8f7000 size:614400 offset:0 fd:64
03-22 14:35:08.593: D/memalloc(1320): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5ca41000 size:614400
03-22 14:35:08.593: D/memalloc(1320): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5dc02000 size:614400
03-22 14:35:08.593: D/memalloc(1320): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5dca8000 size:614400
03-22 14:35:09.775: D/memalloc(1320): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5ca41000 size:614400 offset:0 fd:60
```

## INFO

Now it behaves slightly differently. Now it only force closes after you click the save button in add_country:

Button android:id="@+id/saveBtn

Comment: did you find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I probably misunderstood and it's probably much more complex than this, but...

```
String normalTimeFormat = CurrentHour + ":" + CurrentMinute;
```

---

```
private void saveContact() 
       {

          DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(this);

          //Here's the new change
          String cHour = timeEt.getCurrentHour().toString();
          String cMinute = minEt.getCurrentMinute().toString();
          String normalTimeFormat = cHour + ":" + cMinute;

          //Do whatever with normalTimeFormat now

          if (getIntent().getExtras() == null)
          {
              dbConnector.insertContact(nameEt.getText().toString(),
                      capEt.getText().toString(),
                      timeEt.getCurrentHour().toString(),
                      minEt.getCurrentMinute().toString(),
                      codeEt.getText().toString());
          }
          else
          {
              dbConnector.updateContact(rowID,
                      nameEt.getText().toString(),
                      capEt.getText().toString(),
                      codeEt.getText().toString());
                }
       }
```

Comment: I think that CurrentHour and CurrentMinute are simply int variable from `TimePicker`. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html#getCurrentHour%28%29

Comment: Can anyone show me how I can implement this in my current source code?

Comment: Could you edit your paste there so it only contains the relevant part of the code?

Comment: There, changed my answer to reflect what you expect.

Comment: Implemented your suggestion - I get 14 new problems when I attempt to do so (I had zero before)

Comment: What new problems? Can't help you if I don't know what they are. - I also editted my original solution, try that now.

Comment: Force closing when clicking the save button in add_country/addEditCountry [logcat and updated source code w your suggestion posted above]

Comment: Also getting 3 "String Cannot be Resolved to a Variable" errors for String cHour, String cMinute and String normalTimeFormat, although I swear I implemented them. (Strange thing is about my implementation is  the references to them at the bottom of the source code don't show in blue like the ones at the top do.)

Comment: I just realized there was something very wrong in the code. Where do you need the normalTimeFormat?

Comment: <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/normalTimeFormat"
    style="@style/StyleText"/>

in view_country.xml

Comment: [I really appreciate your help fcm! I really need it...]

Comment: FCM - can you explain the "something very wrong" in the code you mentioned earlier? (I'm dying to get past this issue and keep working on this project)

Answer (score 0):

You can use formatted strings:

```
int hour = 9;
int minute = 30;
String format = "%d:%d";
String time = String.format (format, hour, minute);

yourTextView.setText (time);
```

Comment: We already showed you how it can be done. Do you also want us to do your other tasks? You have to do some work yourself.

Comment: FCM noticed an issue with the source posted above... can you spot it by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Probably I'm missing some implementation details, but you could just store the `System.currentTimeinMillis()` and then do something like

```
Date date = new Date(timeStampFromSQLite);
String currentDate = date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes();
```